# nm-applet menu pops up too high, in LXDE

Tags: debian, networkmanager, lxde

I've got a fresh install of Debian 12 with LXDE on my laptop, and I installed NetworkManager and nm-applet (via the `network-manager-gnome` package).  My problem is, when I click (left or right) on the nm-applet icon in the system tray, the menu pops up too high on my screen.  It's as if the applet thinks my cursor is higher than it is, or that the panel is taller than it is.  Here's a screenshot.

[image: after clicking on the tray icon, the nm-applet menu appears too high]

Not sure if this is a problem with the applet or LXDE.  I've searched around and haven't found anything similar to my problem.  Any ideas?